# Prove that a vector outside of Span join to an independet set

Tags: linear-algebra

Given vector space $V$, $B = \{{v_1, v_2, ... , v_n\}}$ an independent set in $V$.
The vector $w \notin Sp(B)$. I need to prove that $\{{v_1, v_2, ... , v_n, w\}}$ is an independent set.
I think - I can say that beause $w$ is not in $Sp(B)$ then it's not a linear combination of $\{{v_1, v_2, ... , v_n\}}$ and therefore $\{{v_1, v_2, ... , v_n, w\}}$ is an independent set.
But it is too short and I don't think it's enough for a proof... Can you help me understand how to write it more mathimatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linear independence means that you cannot write a linear "dependence" on the vectors. So suppose that $\{v_1, \dots, v_n, w\}$ are not linearly independent. We can write a non-trivial linear relation (i.e., at least one of the coefficients is nonzero):
$ c_1 v_1 + \dots + c_n v_n + c w = 0$.

If $c = 0$, then you have a linear relation $c_1 v_1+ \dots + c_n v_n = 0$, but the set $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ was linearly independent, so this cannot be a non-trivial linear relation.

If $c\neq 0$, then you can write $\frac{-1}{c} \left ( c_1 v_1 + \dots + c_n v_n\right) = w$, which means $w$ is in the span of $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$.  Specifically $w = \frac{-c_1}{c} v_1 + \dots + \frac{-c_n}{c} v_n$, so I can write $w$ as a linear combination of $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$. This contradicts that $w$ is not in the span of $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$.

It is also worth clarifying what linear independence means. When we say $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ is linearly independent, we mean that if $c_1 v_1+ \dots+ c_n v_n = 0$ then $c_1 = c_2 = \dots = c_n = 0$. The only way to "combine" the vectors to get zero is to (scalar) multiply each by 0.

When you first learn linear algebra, it is easy to misunderstand the definition of "linear independence". You might think it means one vector is not in the span in the remaining vectors (like you hinted at in your question). For example, $[1 ~ 0]$ is not in the span of $[0 ~ 1]$ and $[0 ~ 2]$. However, $[1 ~ 0]$, $[0~1]$, and $[0~2]$ is not a linearly independent set. So the precise definition is actually important.

Comment: I didn't understand the last passage... If it's not zero than it's a contradiction? to what? are you saying the statement is false?

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify the last part. Does it make sense? Our assumption was that $w$ was not in the span of $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$. So if we can write $w$ as a linear combination of $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$, then that contradicts our assumption.

Comment: Thanks! Why -1 and not 1 ?

Comment: Nevermind I got it! Thanks so much

Answer (score 3):

To prove $v_1,\dots,v_n,w$ is a linearly independent set, take an arbitrary linear combination of these vectors and show the coefficients must all be zero. Say $c_1,\dots,c_{n+1} \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$c_1 v_1+ \cdots + c_nv_n + c_{n+1}w=0.$$
What happens if $c_{n+1} \neq 0$? (Hint: solve for $w$.) What about if $c_{n+1}=0$? (Use the fact that $v_1,\dots,v_n$ are linearly independent.)

Comment: If $c_{n+1} = 0$ then I have the former set (without $w$) and I know it is independent. When $c_{n+1} \neq 0$ it will never equal to any of the other vectors because $w$ is not in $Sp(B)$ therefore also $a \cdot w$ is not in $Sp(B)$... And then what? Am I even right?

Comment: Yes, if $c_{n+1}\neq 0$, you get a contradiction because $w$ is not in the span of the other vectors. So $c_{n+1}=0$, and as you pointed out you're left with a linear combination of $v_1, \dots,v_n$ that equals zero. So what does that imply about $c_1, \dots, c_n$?